# Table sort by total column in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to sort the table by total value. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65388204/how-to-sort-the-table-to-order-by-points-at-end-of-column-using-javascript/65389242#65389242). This works but it fails when two table elements have same point.

I am trying to sort the table using javascript to order by total points at the end. The table is a dynamic one so W1, W2, W3 columns adds up to total.  Each row is dynamically created as well.

Please help

```js
const sortTotal = () => {
  const tbl = [...document.getElementsByClassName("fl-table")][0];
  const tbody = [...tbl.tBodies][0];
  const oObjects = [];

  [...tbody.rows].forEach(row => {
    const cells = [...row.cells];
    const obj = [...row.cells].map(cell => {
        return cell.innerHTML;
    });
    oObjects.push(obj);
  });

  oObjects.sort((a, b) => a[a.length -2] > b[b.length -2] ? 1 : -1);

  [...tbody.rows].forEach((row, i) => {
    [...row.cells].forEach((cell, j) => {
        cell.innerHTML = oObjects[i][j];
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="sortTotal()">
  Sort</button>
</button>
<table class="fl-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Player Name</th>
      <th>W1</th>
      <th>W2</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="agl-profile-img-new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70C/O https://placeholder.com/"></td>
      <td>Heather Rankin</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="agl-profile-img-new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70C/O https://placeholder.com/"></td>
      <td>Stephen Puopolo</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="agl-profile-img-new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70C/O https://placeholder.com/"></td>
      <td>Latheesh V M V</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Should the sort function just be `oObjects.sort((a, b) => a.total > b.total ? 1 : -1);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting by wrong column.
`a[a.length -2] > b[b.length -2]`
should be
`a[a.length -1] > b[b.length -1]`
and sort will make 25, 4, 4 by total